# selectByIndex(data) in Selenium Hybrid Framework for random values of dropdown

Tags: selenium-webdriver, dropdown

I'm using Hybrid Framework i.e. Object, Data and Keyword all along. I'm stuck in selecting a random value of dropdown as per its Index.

In my input file where I have mentioned the test data [Test Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smMG2.png) there is a column WorkGroup in integer i.e. I've given input for Dropdown in integer form which is nothing but index value of dropdown. Now in 2nd image you can see that se.selectByIndex(data) is causing troubles.

Error is:

> The method selectByIndex(int) in the type Select is not applicable for the arguments (String)

[Code where error comes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e47tI.png)

```
public  String selectDropdown(String object,String data){
    APP_LOGS.debug("Selecting dropdown values.");               
    try{
        WebElement _directoryDDL = driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty(object)));
            Select se = new Select(_directoryDDL);
            se.selectByIndex(data); // This is where error is coming. I need to use only index.
            return Constants.KEYWORD_PASS;
        }
    catch(Exception e1){
        return Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL+" Control not found.";
        }
    }
```

I can't go with **selectByValue** or **selectByVisibleText** because per user the value of dropdown changes. That's why only index value is the only solution here.

Comment: The reason why it's giving this error is because I am giving data in argument which is coming from excel sheet. Doesn't matter it's 0 or 1 in excel but for the code it's in String format. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says you are passing a String to where an int is required. Use `Integer.parseInt(String s)` or `Integer.parseUnsignedInt(String s)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**selectByIndex** method expects an Integer argument, whereas you are passing the parameter **data** which is a String type. That's why it's giving an error. Here's the code to convert String into Integer.

```
se.selectByIndex(Integer.parseInt(data));
```

Comment: valueOf is also working :) Thanks for taking your time out for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert string into the integer depending on the Language you are using with Selenium WebDriver.

[Convert a String to a Number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb397679.aspx)

Make sure the input string is a number, i.e. "1", "0", etc. Otherwise you will get an exception.